# Generate distribution based on mean and sd multiple times for different groups

Tags: r, list, dplyr, replicate

I have a dataframe composed of a grouping variable, mean, and sd. I'd like to generate a number of means (eg., 10) for each group based on their group mean and sd. I can do this using rnorm coupled with the dplyr function "mutate", but I'm having trouble doing this multiple times and compiling the lists into a dataframe with labeled replicates.

```
Group = c("A","B","C","D","E") 
Mean = c(1.25,5.5,3.25,1,5) 
SD = c(2.5,3,2.25,2,5.35) 
df = data.frame(Group,Mean,SD)

df

#works for one rep
df%>%
  group_by(Group)%>%
  mutate(est_mean=rnorm(1,mean=Mean,sd=SD))

#replicated 10 times but in list form
replicate(10, df%>%
        group_by(Group)%>%
        mutate(est_mean=rnorm(1,mean=Mean,sd=SD)))
```

> Blockquote

Ultimately I would like to end up with a dataframe with group, Mean, SD, the estimated mean, and the ID number based on the replicate number (in this example it would be 1 to 10). Below is an example of what the first 5 rows would like like.

```
Group  Mean    SD      est_mean  ID
 A     1.25   2.50     3.07      1
 B     5.50   3.00     7.64      1
 C     3.25   2.25     2.90      1
 D     1.00   2.00     0.11      1
 E     5.00   5.35     1.03      1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want the same df generated 10 times with different means for each group, 10 different times? If so, here is slightly hacky way to accomplish something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

Group = c("A","B","C","D","E") 
Mean = c(1.25,5.5,3.25,1,5) 
SD = c(2.5,3,2.25,2,5.35) 
df = data.frame(Group,Mean,SD)

df
#>   Group Mean   SD
#> 1     A 1.25 2.50
#> 2     B 5.50 3.00
#> 3     C 3.25 2.25
#> 4     D 1.00 2.00
#> 5     E 5.00 5.35

map_df(1:10, ~df) %>% 
    mutate(ID = rep(1:10, each=5),
           est_mean = map2(Mean, SD, ~rnorm(1, .x, .y)))
#>    Group Mean   SD ID   est_mean
#> 1      A 1.25 2.50  1 -0.1511891
#> 2      B 5.50 3.00  1   4.809468
#> 3      C 3.25 2.25  1   6.757094
#> 4      D 1.00 2.00  1   1.141017
#> 5      E 5.00 5.35  1   5.691689
#> 6      A 1.25 2.50  2   5.537662
#> 7      B 5.50 3.00  2   6.882749
#> 8      C 3.25 2.25  2  0.4036122
#> 9      D 1.00 2.00  2 -0.3737057
#> 10     E 5.00 5.35  2   2.615708
#> 11     A 1.25 2.50  3   4.310204
#> 12     B 5.50 3.00  3   6.579441
#> 13     C 3.25 2.25  3   4.151736
#> 14     D 1.00 2.00  3   1.221365
#> 15     E 5.00 5.35  3    2.02625
#> 16     A 1.25 2.50  4   5.717283
#> 17     B 5.50 3.00  4   6.993551
#> 18     C 3.25 2.25  4  -1.174889
#> 19     D 1.00 2.00  4   2.402712
#> 20     E 5.00 5.35  4   2.470566
#> 21     A 1.25 2.50  5  -1.419559
#> 22     B 5.50 3.00  5   4.846075
#> 23     C 3.25 2.25  5    0.94149
#> 24     D 1.00 2.00  5 -0.4577825
#> 25     E 5.00 5.35  5    1.65604
#> 26     A 1.25 2.50  6  -2.966733
#> 27     B 5.50 3.00  6   8.013361
#> 28     C 3.25 2.25  6    3.59509
#> 29     D 1.00 2.00  6  -1.276274
#> 30     E 5.00 5.35  6   11.70791
#> 31     A 1.25 2.50  7   2.316161
#> 32     B 5.50 3.00  7   4.614786
#> 33     C 3.25 2.25  7   5.264033
#> 34     D 1.00 2.00  7   2.756267
#> 35     E 5.00 5.35  7   9.395459
#> 36     A 1.25 2.50  8   2.971601
#> 37     B 5.50 3.00  8   7.161753
#> 38     C 3.25 2.25  8   3.110699
#> 39     D 1.00 2.00  8  0.3880747
#> 40     E 5.00 5.35  8    2.96448
#> 41     A 1.25 2.50  9 -0.4867674
#> 42     B 5.50 3.00  9   4.876248
#> 43     C 3.25 2.25  9  0.4028582
#> 44     D 1.00 2.00  9   5.337912
#> 45     E 5.00 5.35  9    11.4626
#> 46     A 1.25 2.50 10  -1.557771
#> 47     B 5.50 3.00 10   4.291345
#> 48     C 3.25 2.25 10   2.200025
#> 49     D 1.00 2.00 10    2.55993
#> 50     E 5.00 5.35 10   4.553975
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help, I love the simplicity of your code. It works great!

Comment: @RyanStephens Glad I could help. Please remember to accept my answer so others with the same problem will know in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I propose another answer without `dplyr` but I am obliged to deal with data type. However I can simulate 10 random variables without calling 10 times the `rnorm` function. I don't know if it is better to call 10 times for one simulation or once for 10 simulations.

Data of the problem :

```
Group = c("A","B","C","D","E") 
Mean = c(1.25,5.5,3.25,1,5) 
SD = c(2.5,3,2.25,2,5.35) 
df = data.frame(Group, Mean, SD)
```

My code is the following :

```
m <- length(Mean)
p <- 10
res <- data.frame(factor("A", level=Group), matrix(0, nrow=m*p, ncol=4))
res[,1] <- rep(Group, each = p)
res[,2] <- rep(Mean, each = p)
res[,3] <- rep(SD, each = p)
res[,4] <- matrix(apply(df, 1, function(row, p){
  rnorm(p, mean=as.numeric(row[2]), sd=as.numeric(row[3]))}, p = p), nrow=p*m, ncol=1)
res[,5] <- rep(seq(1, p), m)

colnames(res) = c("Group", "Mean", "SD", "Est_Mean", "Indices")
res = res[order(res$Indices), ]
```